# How To Roll Back Accidental Direct Unit Test Proc Call?

Tags: tsqlt

I am starting to dabble in tSQLt and a few times have accidentally hit F5 and executed my test proc directly instead of through tSQLt.RunAll, which hoses my entire database. Is there any simple way to roll back that accidental execution instead of restoring my entire database from backup?

The full error is [myDClass].[test myTest] failed: (Error) There is already an object named 'pMyProc_SpyProcedureLog' in the database.[16,6]{,1} (There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.{tSQLt.Private_RunTest,162})

I checked DBCC OPENTRAN but there aren't actually any transactions listed.

Comment: In your case, you may only need to ROLLBACK, then DROP TABLE pMyProc_SpyProcedureLog. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60432346/303101) is more comprehensive if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I needed.